# D3.js - Drawing points on map fails due to wrong projection

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson, esri

I'm currently working on a project which draws a map based on geo data from a JSON file using D3.js.

Now I have another JSON file with locations in it and I want to draw those locations as points on my map.

I'm doing this as follows:

```
svg.selectAll('circle')
.data(redCrossLocations.features)
.enter()
.append('circle')
.attr('cx', function(d) {
  var x = d.geometry.x
  var y = d.geometry.y
  return projection([x.toString(), y.toString()])[0]
})
.attr('cy', function(d) {
  var x = d.geometry.x
  var y = d.geometry.y
  return projection([x.toString(), y.toString()])[1]
})
.attr('r', 10)
.attr('text',function(d) {
  return d.attributes.DienstSt
})
.style('fill', 'yellow')
```

But when I have a look at the circles with Firebug those circles have very high `cx` and `cy` values which do not fit the map coordinates at all. As a result, the points are not positioned and not visible on the map.

This is how it looks like when investigating the html with Firebug:

```
<svg id="chart-330a29bc-10a6-422f-b7a4-b79213e63a0f" viewBox="0 0 1700 850">
<g transform="">
<svg width="425" height="425">
<rect width="850" height="850" style="stroke: black; fill: none;">
<path d="M406.7479670817884,199.90340867304621L407.06008919224314,199.57933852526912L407.7100188308723,198.8568991193315L408.1015443102342,198.34893921523326L408.14613950961393,198.29087863446694L408.68509042962614,197.6062181990019L408.79620200385034,197.4452283080136L409.08485295673836,197.0327872268681L409.31646456821454,196.6144688478962L409.62291817269215,195.96797874850017L409.78145919928556,195.49428734522007L409.912011977608,194.9738064907906L409.986809685407,194.39973754590756L410.0058080374765,193.7122278...00837217,205.1538807821671L401.9104729365481,204.65327053784495L402.62461611946765,203.79979531967183L403.17787116003547,203.1799602826395L403.20639083074093,203.1993550356201L403.308689649577,203.08799997778988L403.42697542668066,202.95942665539405L403.5903878256004,202.78322302641755L405.8101836239257,200.80217267343687L405.8688615178462,200.74629337105216L405.89149125655877,200.7271611214237L405.95836191302715,200.66712537209605L406.1133158381808,200.52594198620864L406.3833670058257,200.28190447086672Z" style="fill: red; stroke-width: 1; stroke: black;">
<circle cx="189993884.995462" cy="-29942.633406634715" r="10" text="Salzburg Stadt" style="fill: yellow;">
<circle cx="186702567.5263016" cy="6214.613271863014" r="10" text="Lamprechtshausen" style="fill: yellow;">
<circle cx="191422937.49531066" cy="NaN" r="10" text="Mattsee" style="fill: yellow;">
<circle cx="196518708.70128453" cy="NaN" r="10" text="StraÃŸwalchen" style="fill: yellow;">
```

In hope that it helps finding a solution, here is the map generating code:

```
const svg = d3.select(`#${chartId}`)
    svg
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width / 2).attr("height", height / 2)

  var center = d3.geo.centroid(salzburg)
  var scale  = 1;
  var offset = [width / 2, height / 2];
  var projection =
    d3.geo.mercator()
      .scale(scale)
      .center(center)
      .translate(offset);

  // create the path
  var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

  // using the path determine the bounds of the current map and use
  // these to determine better values for the scale and translation
  var bounds  = path.bounds(salzburg);
  var hscale  = scale * width  / (bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0]);
  var vscale  = scale * height / (bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1]);
  var scale   = (hscale < vscale) ? hscale : vscale;
  var offset  = [width - (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2.1,
    height - (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2.4];

  projection = d3.geo.mercator().center(center)
    .scale(scale).translate(offset);
  path = path.projection(projection);

  svg.append("rect").attr('width', width).attr('height', height)
    .style('stroke', 'black').style('fill', 'none');

  svg.selectAll("path").data(salzburg.features).enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("fill", "red")
    .style("stroke-width", "1")
    .style("stroke", "black")
```

The `redCrossLocations` look like this:

```
"features": [{
    "attributes": {
      "OBJECTID": 1,
      "DienstSt": "Salzburg Stadt",
      "Art": "Bezirksstelle",
      "Ort": "Salzburg",
      "Strasse": "SterneckstraÃŸe",
      "Hnr": "32",
      "Bezirk": "Stadt Salzburg und Flachgau",
      "Typ": null
    },
    "geometry": {
      "x": 429395.48199999984,
      "y": 296716.59500000067
    }
  }, {
    "attributes": {
      "OBJECTID": 2,
      "DienstSt": "Lamprechtshausen",
      "Art": "Ortsstelle",
      "Ort": "Lamprechtshausen",
      "Strasse": "SchulstraÃŸe",
      "Hnr": "1",
      "Bezirk": "Stadt Salzburg und Flachgau",
      "Typ": null
    },
    "geometry": {
      "x": 421963.38900000043,
      "y": 317197.9179999996
    }
  },
...
```

Does anyone know, why I get this absolutely wrong point coordinates?

Comment: What does your `redCrossLocations.features` look like? Why do you call `.toString()` on your x and y values?

Comment: Not related to your actucal problem, but for both `cx` and `cy` you are accessing the first element of the projected point, i.e. you access the first value `[0]` of the returned array, which is why `cx` and `cy` have identical values.

Comment: @altocumulus I have added the json now; because the location is delivered is a number and I have read that it has to be a string, but it is possible that it does not have an effect in both positive and negative way.

Comment: @altocumulus thank you for telling me that, but it makes it even worse, because now I have not only high values but also NaN values

Comment: Your JSON is [Esri's](https://www.esri.de/) JSON format which is not compatible with GeoJSON which is required by D3. Have a look at the following question about conversion between formats: [*How to convert ArcGIS Server JSON to GeoJSON?*](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13029/how-to-convert-arcgis-server-json-to-geojson)

Comment: @altocumulus I have done the transformation now, but unfortunately it does not have any effect

Comment: @altocumulus yes, it works now, i have taken the wrong EPSG before

Comment: Why did you make such drastic changes to your JSON? The current version (introduced by rev. 4) is GeoJSON  which doesn't resemble the original Esri JSON anymore. This feels like putting one part of the answer into the question. I'd like to suggest rolling back that change.

Comment: @altocumulus I have done the rollback as suggested now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when searching for details taken from your `redCrossLocations` it appears to be downloaded from this [source](https://www.data.gv.at/katalog/dataset/land-sbg_dienststellen-des-roten-kreuzes-land-salzburge12e3/resource/2b36ced1-7b6b-4b57-b84a-f316e71fcb56). Inspecting the full file reveals two issues with your geo input data:

1. Your JSON seems to be Esri's [JSON format](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/index.html?geometry.html), wheras D3 expects GeoJSON as its input. Because your JSON is not compatible with GeoJSON you will have to convert it.
2. The file has a definition of `"spatialReference":{"wkid":31258,"latestWkid":31258}` which refers to the projected coordinate system [*MGI_Austria_GK_M31*](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/pcs.html#31258) (EPSG::31258) which is also not the right one to use when it comes to D3. To make it usable for D3 you need to transform it to the geographic coodinate system [*WGS 84*](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/gcs.html#4326) (EPSG::4326).

Fortunately, you can use the [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) tool to do both conversions in a single run:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" -t_srs "EPSG::4326" "RotesKreuz_Dienststellen.json"
```

Additionaly, there is an option `-s_srs` available, to explicitely specify the source coordinate system (`-s_srs "EPSG:31258"`) which is not needed in your case, because this will be derived from the input file.

There is also a ogr2ogr [web client](http://ogre.adc4gis.com/) available to do the conversion and transformation online. Using that form you may upload your file and specify the "Target SRS" to be `EPSG:4326` which will transform the coordinate system and convert it to GeoJSON.